# Why does nuclear matter tend to maximize pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm reading a text about equations of state of dense nuclear matter. It is often stated that the phase with maximum pressure is preferred. Why is that?

Comment: I suggest to extend your question with at least a single reference (citate or link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because we have to use the grand canonical potential $\Omega$ which is directly related to the pressure: $\Omega /V=-P$ (This can be derived by Legendre transformations starting from $E=TS-pV+\mu N$)

So if you maximize the pressure you actually minimize the free energy (density) (because of the minus sign) so you are looking for the state with the lowest free energy.

Comment: alright, but what about the additional term $\mu N$. That does not appear in the free energy.

Comment: Yeah why should it? To clarify: The grand canonical potential that I use here is sometimes called Landau free energy and is defined as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_potential. Since you allow for particle exchange you have to transform the part with the chemical potential away...